# data stored in list not accessible for another MYSQL query in flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I want the data sent from the form to make a query which gets me the StudentID for 4 Students based on the inputed names.
After this i want to store all these StudentID in another table which have 4 columns as Student1, Student2, Student3, Student4. Each Column stores the id for each respective student.

I'm new to flask and my approach may be entirely wrong. Any suggetions are welcomed.
I'm doubtful if i can use multiple cursor.execute commands per function too.

Here is my Code:

```
@app.route("/group", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def group():
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='somepassword', database ='somedatabase')
cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered = True)

stud1 = request.form.get('student1')
stud2 = request.form.get('student2')
stud3 = request.form.get('student3')
stud4 = request.form.get('student4')
# stud1 to stud 4 store the names of four student

query = (" SELECT StudentID FROM Students "
    " WHERE Name = '%s' OR Name = '%s' OR Name = '%s' OR Name = '%s'" %(stud1,stud2,stud3,stud4))
cursor.execute(query)

data1 = cursor.fetchall()
# data1 as tuple contains all the 4 studentID 
mylist = []
for row in data1:
    mylist.append(' '.join(str(x) for x in row))

# mylist is used to get the values stored in data1 in proper format

_query = (" INSERT INTO Groups(Student1, Student2, Student3, Student4)"
    " VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s )", (mylist[0],mylist[1], mylist[2],mylist[3]))

# here is my problem, the error i get is, list index out of range

cursor.execute(_query)
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
return render_template('forms.html')
```

Based on the error it means mylist is empty, but if i skip the second query and just store the result in mylist and print, it works.
For the second query i tried storing the values as dictionary but it was of no help

```
_query = (" INSERT INTO Groups(Student1, Student2, Student3, Student4)"
        " VALUES ( %(st1)s, %(st2)s, %(st3)s, %(st4)s )")
     data_query = {
     'st1' : mylist[0],
     'st2' : mylist[1],
     'st3' : mylist[2],
     'st4' : mylist[3]
     }
     cursor.execute(_query,data_query)
```

my html code:

```
<form method ="post" action = "/group">
    <label>Student1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="student1">
    <label>Student2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="student2">
    <label>Student3:</label>
    <input type="text" name="student3">
    <label>Student4:</label>
    <input type="text" name="student4">
    <input type="submit" value ="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you print _query to see what is in there after parsing the student information in there?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I tried doing that but it still gives the error, list index out of range!

Comment: Ok, being more clear: Print data1, mylist, the way you do that, and add that to the question please so it becomes more understandable what happens.